# nestjs graphql global guard

Tags: angular, graphql, nestjs

I'm trying to implement a global guard so that by default all requests that receive MUTATIONS from graphql need the token in their headers.

The latter works perfectly with the following code:

**graphql-context-get-token.guard.ts**

```js
    import { ExecutionContext, Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
    import { GqlExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/graphql';
    import { AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
    
    @Injectable()
    export class graphqlContextGetToken extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
      getRequest (context: ExecutionContext){
        const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);    
        return ctx.getContext().req;
      }
    }
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
    @Module({
      imports: [    
        ConfigModule.forRoot({
          isGlobal: true
        }),
        TypeOrmModule. forRoot({
          type: 'postgres',
          host: 'localhost',
          port: 5432,
          username: 'postgres',
          password: '123456789',
          database: 'admin-emperator',
          entities: ['dist/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
          synchronize: true,
        }),
        GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloDriverConfig>({
          driver: ApolloDriver,
          autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/qraphql-schema.gql'),
        }),
        UsersModule, 
        AuthModule, 
        EmployeeModule,
      ],
      controllers: [],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: APP_GUARD,
          useClass: graphqlContextGetToken
        },
      ],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

my problem is that i need to create a decorator that when entering a flag by metadata allows the route that the decorator has, for example **@Ispublic()** not to be taken into account by the guard

**user.resolver.ts**

```js
     /* DECORATOR HERE */
     @Query(()=>[UserEntity], {name: 'getAllUsers'})
        async findAll(@Context() context): Promise<UserEntity[]> {
            return this.userService.findAll();
        }
```

Before using graphql I used this decorator that fulfilled the task:

**public.decorator.ts**

```js
    import { SetMetadata } from '@nestjs/common';
    export const IsPublic = () => SetMetadata('isPublic', true);
```

and my guard had the following logic:

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class AccessTokenGuard extends AuthGuard('jwt') {
      constructor(private reflector: Reflector) {
        super();
      }
    
      canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
        const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride('isPublic', [
          context.getHandler(),
          context.getClass(),
        ]);
        
        return isPublic ? true : super.canActivate(context);
      }
    }
```

but I have not managed to achieve the same result using graphql.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should jsut need to add that `getRequest` from the `graphqlContextGetToken` guard to the `AccessTokenGuard`, right? Or have the `AccessTokenGuard` extend the `graphqlContextGetToken` class

Comment: Thanks [Jay McDoniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/497828/ahmad-alfy), that resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

this post is from a long time ago, but I hope it can help others.

Since GraphQL receives a different type of data in the incoming request, the execution context received by the guards and interceptors is somewhat different with GraphQL compared to REST.

Visit https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/other-features#other-features

You can override getRequest method in the guard

```
...

getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
   const ctx = GqlExecutionContext.create(context)
   return ctx.getContext().req
}


canActivate(context: ExecutionContext) {
   const isPublic = this.reflector.getAllAndOverride('isPublic', [
          context.getHandler(),
          context.getClass(),
   ]);
   return isPublic ? true : super.canActivate(context)
}
```